# Optical Character Recognition using Neural Networks in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

This code is for OCR using ANN ,it contains one hidden layer, the input is an image of size 28x28.the code runs without any error but the output is not at all accurate even after giving 5000+ images for training.I am using the mnist dataset which is of the form of jpg images.  Please tell me what is wrong with my logic.

```
            import numpy as np
            from PIL import Image
            import random
            from random import randint
            y = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
            W1 =  [[ random.uniform(-1, 1) for q in range(40)] for p in range(784)]
            W2 = [[ random.uniform(-1, 1) for q in range(10)] for p in range(40)]
            def sigmoid(x):
                global b
                return (1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-x)))

            #run the neural net forward

            def run(X, W):
                return sigmoid(np.matmul(X,W)) #1x2 * 2x2 = 1x1 matrix

            #cost function

            def cost(X, y, W):  
                nn_output = run(X, W)
                return ((nn_output - y))

            def gradient_Descent(X,y,W1,W2):
                alpha = 0.12    #learning rate
                epochs =  15000 #num iterations
                for i in range(epochs):
                    Z2=sigmoid(np.matmul(run(X,W1),W2))  #final activation function(1X10))
                    Z1=run(X,W1)   #first activation function(1X40)
                    phi1=Z1*(1-Z1)  #differentiation of Z1
                    phi2=Z2*(1-Z2)  #differentiation of Z2
                    delta2 = phi2*cost(Z1,y,W2)  #delta for outer layer(1X10)
                    delta1 = np.transpose(np.transpose(phi1)*np.matmul(W2,np.transpose(delta2)))
                    deltaW2 = alpha*(np.matmul(np.transpose(Z1),delta2))
                    deltaW1 = alpha*(np.matmul(np.transpose(X),delta1))
                    W1=W1+deltaW1
                    W2=W2+deltaW2

            def Training():

                for j in range(8):
                    y[0][j]=1
                    k=1
                    while k<=15: #5421
                        print(k)
                        q=0
                        img = Image.open('mnist_jpgfiles/train/mnist_'+str(j)+'_'+str(k)+'.jpg')
                        iar = np.array(img)     #image array
                        ar=np.reshape(iar,(1,np.product(iar.shape)))
                        ar=np.array(ar,dtype=float)
                        X = ar
                        '''
                        for p in range(784):

                            if X[0][p]>0:

                                X[0][p]=1

                            else:

                                X[0][p]=0
                        '''         
                        k+=1
                        gradient_Descent(X,y,W1,W2)
                        print(np.argmin(cost(run(X,W1),y,W2)))
                        #print(W1)

                    y[0][j]=0
            Training()

            def test():
                global W1,W2
                for j in range(3):
                    k=1
                    while k<=5: #890
                        img = Image.open('mnist_jpgfiles/test/mnist_'+str(j)+'_'+str(k)+'.jpg')
                        iar = np.array(img)     #image array
                        ar=np.reshape(iar,(1,np.product(iar.shape)))
                        ar=np.array(ar,dtype=float)
                        X = ar/256
                        '''
                        for p in range(784):

                            if X[0][p]>0:

                                X[0][p]=1

                            else:

                                X[0][p]=0
                        '''     
                        k+=1
                        print("Should be "+str(j))
                        print((run(run(X,W1),W2)))
                        print((np.argmax(run(run(X,W1),W2))))
            print("Testing.....")
            test()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your cost function, because you simply calculate the difference between the hypothesis output with the actual output.It makes your cost function linear, so it's strictly increasing(or strictly decreasing), which can't be optimized.
 You need to make a cross-entropy cost function(because you use sigmoid as activation function).
 Also, gradient descent simply can't optimize ANN cost function, you should use back-propagation with gradient descent to optimize it.

Comment: as u suggested i used 0.5*np.square(nn_output-y) as the cost function.now on running i am getting a good reduction in cost due to gradient descent but   am not getting the correct output as np.argmax(run(run(X,W1),W2)) gives a different output whose cost is high....[[  3.370e-05   4.999e-01   4.999e-01   4.999e-01  4.999e-01   4.999e-01   4.999e-01   4.999e-01  4.999e-01   4.999e-01]]
[[ 0.99178966  0.99999857  0.99999872  0.99999861  0.99999876  0.99999857  0.99999842  0.99999868  0.99999857  0.99999874]]

Comment: above, the cost output is:- [[  3.370 e-05   4.999 e-01   4.999 e-01   4.999 e-01  4.999 e-01   4.999 e-01   4.999 e-01   4.999 e-01  4.999 e-01   4.999 e-01]]  and the run output is:- [[ 0.99178966  0.99999857  0.99999872  0.99999861  0.99999876  0.99999857  0.99999842  0.99999868  0.99999857  0.99999874]]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with ANN but when working with gradient descent algorithm for regression problems like in Andrew Nag Machine Learning course in coursera, I found it is helpful to have learning rate alpha less than 0.05 and no of iterations more than 100000.
Try tweaking your learning rate then create a confusion matrix which will help you understand the accuracy of your system.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience there are a lot of things that can go wrong with an ANN. I'll list some possible errors for you to consider.

Assuming the classification accuracy does not increase at all after training.

- Something is wrong with the training or testing sets.
- Too high
  learning rates can sometimes cause the algorithm to not converge at
  all. Try setting it very small like 0.01 or 0.001. If there is still no convergence. The issue probably has to do with something else than the gradient descent.

Assuming the training does increase but the accuracy is worse than expected.

- The normalisation process is not correctly implemented. For images it is recommended to use zero-mean-unit-variance.
- The learning rate is too low or too high